# How to Remove css3 transitions to child elements of div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to remove child element transitions in CSS.

Here my problem is,

I have a div that consists of one H1 tag and one div (the div contains one P tag).

When I apply transition to parent div it's applying to the child elements also. But it is not needed.

How can I disable the transitions for child elements?

Here my parent div CSS code snippet:

```
-webkit-transition: width .75s ease;
   -moz-transition: width .75s ease;
     -o-transition: width .75s ease;
        transition: width .75s ease;
```

The transitions is applied when parent width changes.

Answer (score 4):

```
-webkit-transition: none;
-moz-transition: none;
-o-transition: none;
-ms-transition: none;
transition: none;
```

Comment: **Never** use `!important`.  Strengthen your selectors instead.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that myself - edited to remove !important flags. I wouldn't say never, just not in this situation.

Comment: @gilly3 `!important` has it's place. use it for disabled buttons etc to keep selector complexity in check =)

Answer (score 3):

Apply a transition of `0s` to all child elements.

```
.myElement *{
    -webkit-transition: width 0s;
       -moz-transition: width 0s;
         -o-transition: width 0s;
            transition: width 0s;
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replay. can i apply this css to my child elements. i mean particular child elements.

Comment: @mani The `*` will take care of all elements under `.myElement`. If you'd rather apply this to specific child elements, just change the selector.

Comment: In this when i hover on the sliders in home page slide it slide right or left and shows the elements in that slider..
while displaying this content it has showing some disturbance.
is it possible remove that?

Comment: Please replicate your problem in the question; a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be useful, as well.